# Error occur when login with switching database when company name is selected which related with $_SESSION

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, mysqli

Im facing a problem Notice: Undefined index: company in C:\xampp\htdocs\new_exp\login.php on line 4
Errors

At here i have 3 database. exp, new_1 and new_2. In exp database have company table which contain id, company_name, and database_name attributes.
There are two database connection that i use which are dbconnection_main.php and dbconnection.php. dbconnection_main.php i used to call ada database which storing company_name and database_name table. Once user selected option of company_name when login in same time it will call the database_name.

The error occur when i login.

This is my index.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
error_reporting(-1);
// Cek Active Link
function ActiveClass($requestUri)
{
    $current_file_name = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php");

    if ($current_file_name == $requestUri)
        echo 'class="active"';
}

        //check already login
        if (!isset($_SESSION['UserId'])) {
            header ('Location: login');
            exit;
        }
        if ($_SESSION['level'] == 'APPROVAL'){
            header ('Location: login');
            exit;
        }

 //Link to page
if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'ManageCategory') {
            $page = "ManageExpenseCategory";
        } else {
            $page = 'dashboard';
        }


//get global notification
include('includes/global.php');

//Get Header
include('includes/header.php'); 


//set global message notification
$msgBox ="";

if (file_exists('pages/'.$page.'.php')) {
            // Load the Page
            include('pages/'.$page.'.php');
        } else {
            // Else Display an Error

            echo '
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <h3>Err</h3>
                        <div class="alertMsg default">
                            <i class="icon-warning-sign"></i> The page "'.$page.'" could not be found.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ';
        }
        include('includes/footer.php');

?>
```

So here is my login.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
error_reporting(-1);
$_SESSION['db_company_name'] = $_POST['company'];

$msgBox = '';
//include notification page
include ('includes/notification.php');

//Include db Page
require_once ('includes/dbconnection.php');

//Include Function page
include ('includes/Functions.php');
//User Login

if(isset($_POST['login']))
{
        $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $Password = encryptIt($_POST['password']);

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT UserId, company_id, FirstName, LastName, Email, Password, level, admin_access, Currency from user WHERE Email = ? AND Password = ? "))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $Password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($UserId_, $CompanyId_, $FirstName_, $LastName_, $Email_, $Password_, $Level_, $Admin_access_, $Currency_);
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->fetch();

        if ($num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows >= 1) 
        {
            session_start();
                $_SESSION['UserId'] = $UserId_;
                $_SESSION['FirstName'] = $FirstName_;
                $_SESSION['LastName'] = $LastName_;
                $_SESSION['level'] = $Level_;
                $_SESSION['admin_access'] = $Admin_access_;
                $_SESSION['Currency'] = $Currency_;
                $_SESSION['company_id'] = $CompanyId_;

                $compId = $_SESSION['company_id'];
                $UserIds = $_SESSION['UserId'];

                $company_q = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM company_setting where company_id = '".$compId."'");
                $company = mysqli_fetch_assoc($company_q);

                $_SESSION['company_name'] = $company['company_name'];

                if ($_SESSION['level'] === 'STAFF'){
                    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=index">';
                }
                else
                { 
                    $msgBox = alertBox($LoginError);
                }
        }
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <div class="panel-body">
                <?php if ($msgBox) {
                    echo $msgBox;
                } ?>
                    <form class="form-horizontal m-t-20" method="post" action="" role="form">
                        <div class="form-group ">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <input class="form-control" onBlur="checkcompany(this.value)" type="email" required placeholder="<?php echo $Emails; ?>" name="email" id="email" autofocus>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" value="" required placeholder="<?php echo $Passwords; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <span id="result"><select name="company" id="company" class="form-control" required><option>company</option></select></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group text-center m-t-40">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-uppercase waves-effect waves-light"><?php echo $SignIn; ?></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
    </div>

<script>
function checkcompany(v)
{
    //alert(v);
    var dataString = 'email='+v;
    //document.getElementById('loginbtn').style.display = "none";

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "checkaccount.php",
       data: dataString,
       cache: true,
       success: function (result){
       $("#result").html(result);
       //document.getElementById('loginbtn').style.display = "block";
       }
    })
}
</script>
```

This is my checkaccount.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
session_start();
include("includes/dbconnection_main.php");

$email = $_POST['email'];
?>

<select name="company" id="company" class="form-control" required>
<option value="">----------------</option>
<?php
$company_q = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM company");
while($company = mysqli_fetch_assoc($company_q))
{
    //connect to sub database
    $conn_hostname = "localhost";
    $conn_database = $company['database_name'];
    $conn_username = "root";
    $conn_password = "";

    $mysqlii = new mysqli($conn_hostname, $conn_username, $conn_password, $conn_database);


    $check_q = mysqli_query($mysqlii, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE Email = '".$email."' AND status = 'ACTIVE' AND password != ''");
    $check = mysqli_num_rows($check_q);
    if (!$check) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($mysqlii));
        exit();
    }

    if($check >= 1)
    {
?>
        <option value="<?php echo $company['company_name']; ?>"><?php echo strtoupper($company['company_name']); ?></option>
<?php 
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqlii);
}
?>
</select>
```

SO this is my dbconnection_main.php

```
    <?php
    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', '0');


    $dbuser="root";
    $dbpassword="";
    $dbname="exp";
    $dbhost="localhost";

    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname);
    ?>
```

And This is my dbconnection.php

```
<?php 
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{
    session_start();
}

$dbuser="root";
$dbpassword="";
$dbname="exp";
$dbhost="localhost";

if($_SESSION['db_company_name'] != '')
{
    $company_name = $_SESSION['db_company_name'];
}else
{
    $company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
    $_SESSION['db_company_name'] = $company_name;
}

$mysqlie = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname);

$get_database_q = mysqli_query($mysqlie, "SELECT * FROM company WHERE company_name = '".$company_name."'") or trigger_error(mysqli_error($mysqlie),E_USER_ERROR);
$get_database = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_database_q);

                if (!$get_database) {
                printf("Errors: %s\n", mysqli_error($mysqlie));
                exit();
                }

$conn_hostname = "localhost";
$conn_database = $get_database['database_name'];
$conn_username = "root";
$conn_password = "";

$mysqli = new mysqli($conn_hostname, $conn_username, $conn_password, $conn_database);

?>
```

I cannot detect the error since it only give me such general error prompt out. I think it might be related with dbconnection.php at this part which related with $_session..

```
if($_SESSION['db_company_name'] != '')
{
    $company_name = $_SESSION['db_company_name'];
}else
{
    $company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
    $_SESSION['db_company_name'] = $company_name;
}
```

Comment: `$_POST['company']` isn't defined yet. You need to check if it is `isset` or not

Comment: i only know the value of ['company'] is from login.php `                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <span id="result"><select name="company" id="company" class="form-control" required><option>company</option></select></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>` Its inside the <form method="post">

Comment: Your <option> entries inside <select> should look like this: <option value="someValue">someName</option>. If you dont provide value attribute then POST variable "company" will not be set.

Comment: look at my checkaccount.php.. i provide the value for the option. ` <option value="<?php echo $company['company_name']; ?>"><?php echo strtoupper($company['company_name']); ?></option>` the option in the login.php im using the ajax POST to call the list of companyname thorugh checkaccount.php

Comment: any ideas? i still stuck at here